# how to get JSON format from array? - swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

How to get JSON format from array? This is my JSON formatter

```
{
  "productName": "Lemonade",
  "transaction": ["[2016-08-01 10:23:42] - Get product in warehouse",
                "[2016-08-01 10:53:22] - Sent to customer"]
}
```

I have an error with this code. I don't know how to get JSON format from transaction array.

```
if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: returnData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]
                    {
                        valSucceeded = (jsonObject["succeeded"] as? Bool)!;
                        valResponseCode = (jsonObject["responseCode"] as? String)!;
                        valResponseDescription = (jsonObject["responseDescription"] as? String)!;
                        valSerialNumber = (jsonObject["serialNumber"] as? String)!;
                        valProductName = (jsonObject["productName"] as? String)!;
                        if let transactionsArray = jsonObject["transactions"] as? Array<AnyObject> {

                            for transact in transactionsArray
                            {
                                if let transactionStr = transact["transactions"] as? String {
                                    valTransactions = transactionStr
                                } else {
                                    valTransactions = ""
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        let entryResult = TraceModel(succeeded: valSucceeded,
                                                     responseCode: valResponseCode,
                                                     responseDescription: valResponseDescription,
                                                     serialNumber: valSerialNumber,
                                                     productName: valProductName,
                                                     transactions: valTransactions);
                        traceArray.append(entryResult);
                    }
```

Comment: `transactionsArray` seems to contains only String. What are you trying to do? Append them into one value? Only get the last one?

Comment: In your JSON the key of the array is "transaction", not "transactions". And then inside the loop each item is just a String, but you're trying to access again a "transactions" key...

Comment: @EricAya I'm very new with ios and swift, the code shold look like this right? `if let transactionsArray = jsonObject["transaction"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
                                for transact in transactionsArray
                                {
                                   valTransactions = transact as? String
                                }
                            }`

Comment: Sure. But now you have another issue: in your loop, you are always assigning the result string to the same `valTransactions` variable. Consequence: this variable will only hold the last string... :)

Comment: `(jsonObject["succeeded"] as? Bool)!` is nonsensical. The result is an forced unwrapped optional anyway, so you can write `jsonObject["succeeded"] as! Bool`. However if the value can be missing use optional binding `if let succeeded = jsonObject["succeeded"] as? Bool { ...`